# Update Laravel eloquent model with array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an array like this:

```
$names = [
    ["id" => 4, "name" => "Zahra"], 
    ["id" => 7, "name" => "Alica"]
];
```

I want to update `users` table using this array. I know how to do using `foreach`, but does it exist smarter and shorter solution? Like this:

```
User::update($name);
```

I have tried to find on the web, but I could not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using collections

```
collect($names);

$names->eachSpread(function ($id, $name) {
    User::find($id)->update(['name' => $name]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but using foreach code size is same and technique is same: at first find and then update. :(

Comment: I interest if is it possible make this using one function and one query.

Comment: Nope. If you can't do it directly in MySQL you can't do it though eloquent, but this technique is called refactoring to collections (there's a book also) and it's the laravel way

Comment: You can however update multiple entries with the same value in one line, but that's not the case here.